# Change an image with onclick() Heigth different

Tags: javascript, html

In a particular context I have to display an image which at the click will display a second image.
I think the problem is not complicated in itself, but here I must admit that I am drying.

the size of the images is different:
the image in fact 247x70
the image out is 247x600

my problem is that i don't see where i can declare the image size out.
because in this case the two images are the same size, for the time being I am cheating
adding a transparent background, but that shifts the design.

if you look the code , its blocked on 247x600

i must use javascript , i cant use on my contexte CSS.

```
   <p>
        <img alt="" src="url-image in" 
style="height: 200px; width: 220px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
</p>


<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "url-image in"") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "url-image out"";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "url-image in"";
        }
    }
</script>
```

How declare the second image?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the image size to be `247x70` when the src is the image-in & `247x600` when the src changes to the image-out but you are not able to figure out how to set the size dynamically?

Comment: Exactly :)   i dont know , i have try many times without succes.

Comment: `"url-image in""` <--- error

Comment: @epascarello I assume that's just a placeholder.

Comment: @hev1 um, no...

Comment: @epascarello I meant that the sources in the question were likely just placeholders and that is not how their code actually looks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the style of an element using `document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`

Answer (score 0):

Just set `.style.width` and `.style.height`.

```
const img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
function changeImage() {

    if (img.src == "url-image in"") 
    {
        img.src = "url-image out"";
        img.style.height = "247px";
        img.style.width = "70px";
    }
    else 
    {
        img.src = "url-image in"";
        img.style.height = "247px";
        img.style.width = "600px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution Allais:
Don't use quotes of the same, which means you're using double quotes three times so it may cause error. Instead try this code :

```
 <p>
    <img alt="" src="url-image in" style="height: 200px; width: 220px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
</p>
<script language="javascript">
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "url-image in") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "url-image out";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "url-image in";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok  think i have drink

cause i have test again..

```
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "url in"") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "url out"";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "urlin"";
        }
    }
</script>
```

well i think i must have drunk something weird, indeed the script works very well from the moment that the width is the same for the two images, the height will be modified automatically.

Sorry , and thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's what I am talking about in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your image has a different size, remove the width and height from the image style attribute.

Just toggle the image and you don't have to worry about the height which will be set automatically based on the original image height & width.

Here is a CodeSandbox link for demo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-image-onclick-u6m7p?file=/index.html

If you want a fixed height before and change later if some images are too large then remove the height from your image tag and set it when the click event is triggered.

`<img alt="" src="url-image in" style="width: 220px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />`

and in your JS

`document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").style.height = "Your Height in px";`

**Example with refactored code to demonstrate the concept**

```js
let image_src = {
  img_1: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  img_2: "https://via.placeholder.com/200"
};

let img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");

img.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.src === image_src.img_1) {
    this.src = image_src.img_2;
    // if you want to change the height - uncomment below
    //this.style.height = "200px";
  } else {
    this.src = image_src.img_1;
    // if you want to change the height - uncomment below
    //this.style.height = "150px";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <img
        alt=""
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        id="imgClickAndChange"
      />
    </p>
    <p>Click on the image to toggle</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```